# How to calculate Response time in a Flex application

Tags: performance, flash, apache-flex, response

I am testing a Flex website. The framework runs on Adobe's cross-platform Flash Player. I need to find the response time of a particular transaction in the website.

In detail:
I have a button in the Flex website, which when clicked opens up a popup after few seconds. I want to find the accurate measure of that time (time taken to open the popup after the button is clicked).

Is there any simple way to do this?
Any browser tools like chrome or firebug or httpwatch can be of any help? If yes, please brief on how to capture the time. Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Chrome or Firebug will not be able to clock an action in Flash Player as you describe.  What you can do is instantiate a Date object at the start and end of an action.  Then subtract the difference by the Date.time property of the start and end objects.

If you wanted to clock the time it took for an HTTP request then Chrome, Firebug, Charles or Fiddler would be beneficial as you probably already know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fiddler you can see the detail of the Timeline and you right click there and you check "Autoscale Chart" there will tell you the measurement. You can see when delayed in sending and the server to respond.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that in one of my databases from way back maybe it helps or can give you an idea!

// Shows you in ms the start up time.

```
creationComplete="callLater(showInitTime)"

<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

        import flash.utils.Timer;

        [Bindable]
        public var t:String;

        private function showInitTime():void {

            // Record the number of ms since the player was initialized.
            t = "App startup: " + getTimer() + " ms";
        }
]]>
</mx:Script>

    <mx:Label id="l1" text="{t}"/>
```